# Set battery notification at specific percentage

Tags: 20.04, battery, notification

I want to be notified when my laptop is at "x"% battery, how can i set this in my ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Battery Full Indicator 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411483/battery-full-indicator-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:maateen/battery-monitor
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install battery-monitor
```

If you want to uninstall Battery Monitor, run:

```
sudo apt remove battery-monitor -y
```

[YouTube Video](https://youtu.be/Ej1nu6Zsdtw)