# Battery Full Indicator 22.04

Tags: 22.04, battery-charging-threshold

It is really helpful that there is a low battery warning, which can be customised. But there is no warning when the battery is full. If left unattended, it will cause battery wear. Is there any method to get a warning when the battery charge has reached 95% or 100%?

I am using 22.04.

Comment: Actually AFAIK battery wear/life is  affected by how many full charges and full discharges it performs (full power cycles) and keeping your battery fully charged all the time thus preventing/limiting fully cycling it, should extend its life.

Comment: A notification is, however, possible ... please see: https://askubuntu.com/q/1157608

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways of doing that ... here is one that is tested on Ubuntu 22.04 using [Upower](https://upower.freedesktop.org/):

- Identify your battery's device reference(name) with `upower -e` like so:

  ```
  upower -e | grep -i "batt"
  ```
- Get battery information by using `upower -i` with the reference(name) of your battery like so:

  ```
  upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  ```
- Refine the `upower -i` output to get only **state** like so:

  ```
  awk '/state:/ {print $2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0)
  ```
- Refine the `upower -i` output to get only **percentage** without "%" like so:

  ```
  awk '/percentage:/ {print 0+$2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0)
  ```
- Use the above knowledge in a script that checks every five minutes to notify you when your battery charge **reaches or exceeds 95%** while it is in the **charging state** like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    state="$(awk '/state:/ {print $2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0))"
    percentage="$(awk '/percentage:/ {print 0+$2}' <(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0))"
    [ "$state" == "charging" ] && [ "$percentage" -ge "95" ] && notify-send -u critical "Battery $percentage% full. Please unplug your AC adapter"
    sleep 300
done
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks buddy! Along with the solution, the way you wrote solution, made it easy to go along.

Comment: I believe the notification won't work if this script is run from cron. What would need to be added for the graphical notification to work from cron?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova Indeed that might be an issue … I believe you will find [xmessage and cron](https://askubuntu.com/q/1452009) helpful.