# Battery saver app like aldente for ubuntu

Tags: power-management, battery, macbook-pro

I have ubuntu dual booted with macos on my macbook pro 2015.

I love how seamlessly everything it runs on ubuntu, but my battery seems to get drained much faster than what it does on macos.

I was looking if there is any app similar to AlDente (macos)
https://github.com/davidwernhart/AlDente-Charge-Limiter
That way, i can use ubuntu by staying plugged-in with out worrying how my battery is getting affected.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1411483

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit battery charging to 80% capacity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34452/how-can-i-limit-battery-charging-to-80-capacity)

Comment: Unfortunately it's mentioned as vendor specific.
It would be great if I can find a way to implement it for MacBooks also

Answer (score 0):

Found, but have not yet tried, the following:

**applesmc-next**

> [applesmc-next](https://github.com/c---/applesmc-next) patches to the Linux kernel that allow setting battery charge thresholds on Intel Apple devices. This includes a [TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) script for use with that system.

- [github.com/c---/applesmc-next](https://github.com/c---/applesmc-next)

**Battery Health Charging**

> [Battery Health Charging](https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/) is a Gnome Extension that provides a graphical user interface to a Gnome environment for setting charging limit (charging threshold) of a laptop.

- [Battery Health Charging home page](https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/)
- [GNOME Extension: Battery Health Charging](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/)
- [github.com/maniacx/Battery-Health-Charging](https://github.com/maniacx/Battery-Health-Charging)

For the Apple Macbook Intel-series chip, [`applesmc-next` is a dependency](https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/device-compatibility/apple-intel-series).

For the Apple Macbook M-series chip, [the current dependency](https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/device-compatibility/apple-m-series) is [Asahi Linux](https://asahilinux.org/).