# Charge limiting on MacBook Pro

Tags: mac

I'm setting up my old MacBook Pro as a Time Machine Server with ubuntu, and was wondering whether someone managed to do charge limiting on a Mac.
[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442563/battery-saver-app-like-aldente-for-ubuntu) has some answers, none of them are Mac-specific though, and I believe this is a hardware-specific thing...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The battery is 100% managed by the UEFI on Intel-based Apple hardware, and only MacOS can interface with the UEFI APIs to make changes 

Answer (score 0):

I've accidentally solved this by setting a charge limit using [bclm](https://github.com/zackelia/bclm) **before** installing Ubuntu. After the installation, the macOS partition is wiped, but the charge limit persists (in the MacBook's SMC) - at 80% capacity, Ubuntu tells me my battery is full and won't charge!

I can't change the charge limit anymore, but I want the laptop to run on the charger anyway ;)

Now let's hope the SMC doesn't get reset...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this kernel module. It supports intel based macbook.

https://github.com/c---/applesmc-next

If **applesmc-next** is compatible and it works, you will be able to set threshold using command-line and gnome shell extension.

**Command line**

```
echo '60' > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
```

**Gnome shell extension**
**Battery Health Charging**

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5724/battery-health-charging/

Some information
https://maniacx.github.io/Battery-Health-Charging/device-compatibility/apple-intel-series